# How does the operating system know which parameter to pass to /etc/init.d/ ?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, init.d, ubuntu-11.04

I've been working with linux for a while but in a rather simple manner.

I understand that scripts in init.d are executed when the os starts but how exactly does it works?

**How does the os know which paramater to pass to a script?**

To start apache I would do sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start. If I run sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 it doesn't work without the start. How does the os pass start to the script?

Comment: I know it's the job of init (see `man init`). Maybe you'll get some insight by looking at it's source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your Linux distro and release, ultimately sysvinit scripts (those scripts in `/etc/init.d/`) are generally run from the symlinks which exist in `/etc/rc[0-6S].d`, by `/etc/init.d/rc`.

Under Ubuntu, you're either using old-style `sysvinit`, or more recently, `upstart`.  Under the upstart management directory (`/etc/events.d/`) you'll find a legacy mode that falls back to the `/etc/init.d/rc` invocation.  Otherwise, `/etc/init.d/rc` is invoked for each runlevel via `/etc/inittab`.

If you examine the logic of `/etc/init.d/rc`, you'll find it defines actions depending on runlevel (`0` & `S` are unconditionally stopped) or script prefix (`S[0-9][0-9]*` scripts start, `K[0-9][0-9]*` (kill) scripts stop).  The numbering of scripts within a runlevel directory (e.g.: `/etc/rc1.d/`) determines the order in which scripts are stopped or started.  Kill scripts are run first, then start scripts.

For more on this, research sysvinit and upstart.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read some tutorial on how runlevels and init scripts work - http://www.debian-administration.org/article/212/An_introduction_to_run-levels seems quite understandable.

In short, the scripts are not called directly, but through symlinks in the /etc/rc.d directories, where n = runlevel. The symlink's names are formatted like this:

```
[K | S] + nn + [string]
```

where nn is a number marking the order in which the scripts are run (lower numbers first) and K or S determines whether to run the script with the "stop" or "start" parameter.